# Declaring Custom Exceptions to use with Firestore Callable Functions and VueJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This far, I tried

## A

```
class MyException extends Error {
  constructor(message, code) {
    super(message);
    this.code = code;
  }
}
exports.MyException = MyException;
```

VueJS says "exports is not defined"

If I simply did

## B

```
exports.MyException = () => {}
```

then Firebase says MyException is not a constructor. When I

`throw new MyException()`

Actually, once the exception is passed through callable functions, would it still be an `instanceOf`?

Should I just go with

## C

```
try {
  let d = await db.collection('x').document('y')
  if (!d.exists) {
    let e = new Error('Document Does not Exist')
    e.code = 'ERR_NO_DOCUMENT'

    throw e
  }
  else {
    return d.data()
  }
}
```

Is **C** a good practice?

Comment: Can you share your full code, from both ends (Cloud Function and Vue.js)? Also, when you say "the exception is passed through callable functions" do you mean you are returning the exception from the Cloud Function to the Vue.js front end?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) for Callable Cloud Functions:

> To ensure the client gets useful error details, return errors from a
>   callable by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an
>   instance of [`functions.https.HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror).

So doing

```
try {
  let d = await db.collection('x').document('y')
  if (!d.exists) {
    let e = new Error('Document Does not Exist')
    e.code = 'ERR_NO_DOCUMENT'

    throw e
  }
  else {
    return d.data()
  }
}
```

will not work.

You need to do, in your Callable Cloud Function, something like:

```
try {
  let d = await db.collection('x').document('y')
  if (!d.exists) {
    let e = new Error('Document Does not Exist')
    e.code = 'ERR_NO_DOCUMENT'

    throw e
  }
  else {
    return d.data()
  }
} catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @renaud I did see `throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);` in the documentation, but wondered if I could throw a more specific error, such as 'email field empty' as the functions.https.HttpsError codes are fixed as per the documentation. HOWEVER, I now noticed that I can add the 3rd field, `details` that seemed to have been absent in every example I have seen. That would solve my issue I think.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed the details parameter!